# Flutter Vertical Drawer

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I'm new to flutter, and after doing some searching, can't find a widget similar to the `Drawer` for the top of the page coming down, instead of the left or right side of the page coming out. Is there such a widget or a way to create one?

Comment: What will happen to system notification? I haven't seen any app doing this. Can you show an example?

Comment: Never mind, I don't think it is a vertical drawer, but instead using a modal from the top that I want. Something similar to the `showModalBottomSheet()` widget, but from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy task, but Flutter is open source. You can create your own version of `Scaffold` and `Drawer` with a vertical orientation. Just copy and modify the source code.

Comment: Never mind, I don't think it is a vertical drawer, but instead using a modal from the top that I want. Something similar to the `showModalBottomSheet()` widget, but from the top. Is there something like this in Flutter?

Comment: Maybe just use `showDialog` with a `SlideTransition` and a custom dialog widget.

Answer (score 0):

As of this date the `Drawer` widget doesn't support this, and there is no 'Vertical Drawer' widget in the Flutter widget catalog.

Thankfully, [Akshath Jain](https://akshathjain.com/) created a nice [`SlidingUpPanel` widget](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) which does the trick nicely. For my use case I just needed it to slide from the bottom. I haven't tested it myself, but there is a `slideDirection` property which you can set to `SlideDirection.DOWN` and it should do what you're asking for.